# XCode tabBarController with custom button navigation

Tags: xcode, tabbarcontroller

I had a question previously that died out and wanted to post a different approach and see if it was possible.

I have a working application that has a UITabBarController that controls 4 distinct UIViewControllers.  I am able to navigate fine through these, but a couple of the loaded views need to load others in order to perform actions.

Is it possible to have a button within a UIViewController that will replace the current view with a different one and still maintain the tab bar on the bottom? possible replacing the current view and advising either the new UIViewController or the owner tabBarController that the relationship is still the same?

I can post code and further clarify if you wish. I am VERY new to XCode so i'm not completely familiar with how everything operates as of yet.

thank you in advance,

Silver Tiger

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add new view to one existed in the tab.

For example, if your view controller in tab is of type navigation based then you can push the other view upon certain event.